# Wordpress: Replacing featured image with video (but only on single posts not homepage excerpts)

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to only apply the function of the plugin called [Replace featured Image with Video](https://wordpress.org/plugins/replace-featured-image-with-video/), to the blog post itself and not the homepage excerpts (so there is a featured image on excerpts and no video, but a video and no image on the post itselft), however I haven't yet succeeded doing so.

I tried working on this part of the code:

(Note that this is just a code snippet of that whole plugin)
    //***********************************************************
    // Replace the video
    //***********************************************************
    function filter_featured_image_to_video( $html, $post_id = 0 ) {

```
global $post;
if ( isset($post) && !empty($post) ) {
    $x = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_related-video', true);
    if (strlen($x) > 0)
        return $x;
}

return $html;

}

if (!is_admin())
    add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'filter_featured_image_to_video' );
```

What made most sense to me was changing *if (!is_admin())* to *if ( !is_admin() && (is_sinlge() )* but that stops the entire site from loading, and leaves a blank screen.

I also tried making a standalone statement only using if (is_single()), but that also makes things go blank.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for achieving this goal, one of them is using an other plugin with a lot of usable stuff called Advanced Custom Fields.

in ACF you can create an extra field "featured video" where you can select a media item per post/page (depends on the settings below creating field). Be sure to set the "field type" to "File" and the "return value" to "file url" In your loop you can call it like

```
<?php echo get_field("featured_video", $postid);  ?>
```

around the url that is echoed you can put your video tags like so:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="<?php echo get_field("featured_video", $postid) ?>" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

note that this is in HTML5 and not always supported by the clients browser

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer. However, will you solution replace the featured image? I am totally novice, so I'm not sure how to implement it.
My thought was that I could simply edit the code of the current plugin since its replacing the image just fine now. I just need it to only happen on the post itself and not on the homepage excerpts where I only want the image to be shown.

Comment: This will not replace the featured image, this will add an extra item to the post editor.

Comment: Ah okay, that's not really what I'm looking for. But I see i didn't really clarify that good enough. That's done now.
But it can't hurt to ask, if you know about another solution?

Comment: Your function actually does the same as i said only my way is much more user friendly and much easier to edit.